# Simple implementation of a "Like/Unlike" toggle in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

**Models:**

```
User 
  has_many :interests
Interest
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :game
Game
  has_many :interests
```

When viewing a Game, `@user` can click "I'm Interested"/"Remove Interest" to create or destroy the associated Interest.

I first made Interests into a nested resource within Games having just `create` and `destroy` actions, but that was pretty unwieldy and hard to follow. Having an Interests Controller alone seemed bulky.

**Is there a simpler way or a better practice for creating such a toggle function that creates/destroys a model?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [thumbs-up](https://github.com/brady8/thumbs_up) gem.